# How can I implement a file download function via OCC?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need an API that will let me download a (e.g. CSV file). I tried to do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{cartId}/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/octet-stream" })
@ApiOperation(hidden = false, value = "Exports the contents of a cart as a CSV file.", notes = "Exports the contents of a cart as a CSV file.")
@ApiBaseSiteIdUserIdAndCartIdParam
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity export() {

    File file = new File("test.csv");

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "test" + ".csv")
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new FileSystemResource(file));
}
```

However, I would get errors like this:

> 0203_17:48:01,878 INFO  [hybrisHTTP21] 
>   [de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.resolver.RestHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException:73]
>   Translating exception
>   [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException]: Could
>   not find acceptable representation 0203_17:48:01,879 WARN 
>   [hybrisHTTP21] 
>   [de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.resolver.AbstractRestHandlerExceptionResolver.writeWithMessageConverters:72]
>   Could not find HttpMessageConverter that supports return type [class
>   de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.dto.error.ErrorListWsDTO] and
>   [application/octet-stream] 0203_17:48:01,879 WARN  [hybrisHTTP21] 
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.logException:197]
>   Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException:
>   Could not find acceptable representation]

I understand this is because springmvc-servlet.xml only has resolverXStreamJSONConverter and resolverXStreamXmlConverter.

If I were to do it the MVC way, I'd write the file to a HttpServletResponse, but that doesn't seem ideal for OCC. So, how should I implement the file download? (Code sample also appreciated)

NOTE: The API/method will be used with Spartacus storefront.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to add org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter in messageConvertersV2 in web/webroot/WEB-INF/config/v2/jaxb-converters-spring.xml:

```
<util:list id="messageConvertersV2">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <ref bean="customJsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <ref bean="customXmlHttpMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>
```

However, not sure if this is correct or a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a similar implementation to offer a PDF download. The controller now returns `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` and I appended the corresponding MessageConverter. I also didnt find a 'better' way, but it works.

```
    <bean id="myByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean depends-on="messageConvertersV2" parent="listMergeDirective">
    <property name="add" ref="myByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
</bean>
```